# How do you display all the tpl.php template files that are being loaded on the current page?

Tags: 7, theming

Is there a function to show all the tpl.php template files being loaded on the page? Also showing the overrides too. I'm looking for a specific tpl file, but i have hundreds of the same tpl file that all have the same code and I'm not sure which file is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

the only thing that comes to mind is to uncomment `$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;` in setting.php. The description for this setting pasted below.

> **Theme debugging:**
>   When debugging is enabled:
>   -- The markup of each template is surrounded by HTML comments that contain   theming information, such as template file name suggestions.
>
> -- Note that this debugging markup will cause automated tests that directly check rendered HTML to fail.    For more information about
>   debugging theme templates, see 
>   https://www.drupal.org/node/223440#theme-debug.
>
> Not recommended in production environments.

If anyone knows of a better way - please share.